# How to call a Layout from itself to make an instance

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I have a Layout(SubMenu100) that have an event to call other Layout(SubMenu200), but it also make a onClick trigger that will create an instance if layout(SubMenu100) and call itself, but I don't know how to get an instance like the next code.

```
this.SubMenu100 = new SubMenu100();
```

I try to put it in Define vars but get me an error.

```
define([
    'backbone.marionette',
    'underscore',
    'logger',
    'tpl!apps/templates/SubMenu100.html',
    'i18n!apps/nls/Messages',
    'apps/views/SubMenu200',
    'apps/views/SubMenu100'
], function (Marionette, _, Logger, Template, i18n, SubMenu200, SubMenu100) {
    launch: function (e) {
        $("#title_wrapper_div").click(this.callMe);
    },
    callMe: function () {            
        if (this.subMenu100 === undefined) {
            this.subMenu100 = new SubMenu100(); // <- here
        }
        window.App.vent.trigger("dashboard:showView",this.subMenu100, "", "", "", "");
    }
}
```

So, this is the question, How can I create an instance of SubMenu100 inside within itself?

Comment: Out of curiosity what is the role of `Marionette` here? You don't seem to be using it...

Comment: Also you are not returning anything from `define` ...?

Answer (score 0):

If `launch` is called with context of `SubMenu100`, you can do `this.callMe.bind(this)` then you should be able to do `new this()` inside `callMe`.

But for simplicity you could do this :

```
define([
    'backbone.marionette',
    'underscore',
    'logger',
    'tpl!apps/templates/SubMenu100.html',
    'i18n!apps/nls/Messages',
    'apps/views/SubMenu200'
  ], function(Marionette, _, Logger, Template, i18n, SubMenu200) {

  var SubMenu100 = Class SubMenu100 {
    launch: function(e) {
      $("#title_wrapper_div").click(this.callMe);
    },
    callMe: function() {
      if (this.subMenu100 === undefined) {
        this.subMenu100 = new SubMenu100();
      }
      window.App.vent.trigger("dashboard:showView", this.subMenu100, "", "", "", "");
    }
  }

  return SubMenu100;
});
```

Note that every `launch` will create new event handler potentially on the same element (unless something else is doing proper cleanup) and this can lead to bugs. I don't recommend using global jQuery selectors in backbone components.

If you want to create instances of `SubMenu100` and `SubMenu200` I'd create a higher level component in charge of that:

```
require([
// ^ ------ this is NOT SubMenu100 definition
'apps/views/SubMenu100',
'apps/views/SubMenu200',
], function (SubMenu100, SubMenu200) {
  // this is NOT SubMenu100 definition
  launch: function (e) {
    $("#title_wrapper_div").click(this.callMe);
  },
  callMe: function () {            
    if (this.subMenu100 === undefined) {
        this.subMenu100 = new SubMenu100();
    }
  }
});
```